# Replace with Python regex in pandas column

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, replace

```
a = "Other (please specify) (What were you trying to do on the website when you encountered ^f('l1')^?Â\xa0)"
```

There are many values starting with '^f' and ending with '^' in a pandas column. And I need to replace them like below :

```
"Other (please specify) (What were you trying to do on the website when you encountered THIS ISSUE?Â\xa0)"
```

Comment: [This](https://regex101.com/r/5KogAg/1) is what you looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't mention what you've tried already, nor what the rest of your DataFrame looks like but here is a minimal example:

```
# Create a DataFrame with a single data point
df = pd.DataFrame(["... encountered ^f('l1')^?Â\xa0)"])

# Define a regex pattern
pattern = r'(\^f.+\^)'

# Use the .replace() method to replace
df = df.replace(to_replace=pattern, value='TEST', regex=True)
```

Output

```
                          0
0  ... encountered TEST?Â )
```